# Loop through Request object keys

Tags: c#, asp.net

This works to loop through all Form keys:

```
foreach (string s in Request.Form.Keys )        
        {       
            Response.Write(s.ToString() + ":" + Request.Form[s] + "<br>");      
        }
```

But, I want to loop through all Request keys:

```
foreach (string s in Request )      
        {       
            Response.Write(s.ToString() + ":" + Request[s] + "<br>");       
        }
```

Problem is request.keys is not a collection.  But clearly the request object has children that I want to loop through.  I'm pretty sure it's possible, I'm just using bad syntax.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use [`Request.Params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx):

```
foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys )     
{       
    Response.Write(s.ToString() + ":" + Request.Params[s] + "<br>");       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mark is correct this will work but it will return all the keys in cookies, the keys in form that is being sent , and the keys in the query strings and other key value pairs being sent. I suggest getting more specific. If you are receiving a Post object use

```
   Dictionary<string, string> _properties;
    foreach (string f in report.Form.Keys)
    {
        _properties.Add(f, report.Form[f]);
    }
```

and for a Get page use

```
    foreach(string s in report.QueryString.Keys)
    {
        _properties.Add(s,report.QueryString[s]);
    }
```

Comment: Realise this is fairly old, but do you mean `Request` not `report`?